# Order By priority not alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to prioritize my query by the `ticket_priority_id`.

The IDs are categorized as `ASAP`, `HIGH`, `MED`, `LOW`.

When I order by `ticket_priority_id` it always puts it in alphabetical order (`LOW` is ahead of `MED`).

How can I make it so I can order by `ticket_priority_id` but not alphabetically but by importance. I want the order to go (from top to bottom) `ASAP` - `HIGH` - `MED` - `LOW`

Comment: See FIELD(). It'll do what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a case statement in your order by like this

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN ticket_priority_id = 'ASAP' THEN 1
        WHEN ticket_priority_id = 'HIGH' THEN 2
        WHEN ticket_priority_id = 'MED' THEN 3
        WHEN ticket_priority_id = 'LOW' THEN 4
        ELSE 5
   END
```

Comment: `ELSE 0` would be more accurate no? Since no priority would mean lower. At least to me.

Comment: @cheesemacfly - That depends on the context but yes, it could be.

Comment: Oh I am so wrong I meant the other way so as in your answer :)

Comment: @cheesemacfly - It looks like you've changed the comment I've responded to invalidating my comment <g>. For the record *(and as you figured out)*: the else statement should be > 4 for something like an 'idle' priority. 0 for something like a 'super duper asap' priority.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
ORDER BY
  FIELD(ticket_priority_id, 'ASAP', 'HIGH', 'MED', 'LOW')
```

Please notice that if `ticket_priority_id` is not present in the following list, it will return 0, so you might want to add also want this:

```
ORDER BY
  ticket_priority_id NOT IN ('ASAP', 'HIGH', 'MED', 'LOW'),
  FIELD(ticket_priority_id, 'ASAP', 'HIGH', 'MED', 'LOW')
```

to put rows that have no priority at the bottom instead of the top.